# Как сделать scroll-track шире чем scroll-thumb?

Tags: html, css

Сделал кастомный скроллбар(нашел). Но не могу понять как сделать бг шире чем сам ползунок. Помогите пожалуйста

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$.browser.webkit) {
    $('.wrapper').html('<p>Sorry! Non webkit users. :(</p>');
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#info {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

a {
  color: #074E8C;
}

.scrollbar {
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 65px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.force-overflow {
  min-height: 450px;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}


/*
 *  STYLE 1
 */

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollbar" id="style-1">
    <div class="force-overflow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

используйте linear-gradient  для scrollbar, меняйте % чтоб получить нужный результат

```
div {
      overflow: auto;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: #fcc;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: linear-gradient(
        to left,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
      );
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: #000;
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]